# How to change the index of a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have two lists like below:

```
A = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [3, 4]], [2, [5, 6]], [3, [7, 8]], [4, [9, 10]], [5, [11, 12]], [6, [13, 14]]]
```

and

```
B = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [4, 5]], [4, [[7, 8], [9, 10]]]]
```

I want to replace some elements of A based on some conditions related to list B.

I have written a code that does what I'm looking for, as below:

```
x = 3
v = [0, 1, 4]

for i in range (x):
    if i in v and B[i][0] == A[i][0]:
        A[i][1][0] = B[i][1][1]

for elem in v:
    if elem not in range(x):

        A[elem][1][0] = B[2][1][1][0]
        A[elem+1][1][0] = B[2][1][1][1]
    else:
        A = A

print (A)
```

My problem is with these lines:

```
for elem in v:
    if elem not in range (x):
        A[elem][1][0] = B[2][1][1][0]
        A[elem+1][1][0] = B[2][1][1][1]
```

As you can see, after looking through the elements of list `v`, and check if those elements are not in `range (x)`, in this case, that element is `4`, I want to  replace  some elements of `A` with some elements of `B` in this case that element is `[4, [[7, 8], [9, 10]]]` , However, the index of this element in list `B` is `2`. Is there any other way to use `4` in `[4, [[7, 8], [9, 10]]]` which is also an element of `v`  inside the code instead of writing `B[2]`?  I want to use `[x[0] for x in B]` as the indicators instead of using the indexes, as those are different.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to stick to the structure of your current code, you could use `np.where` for this

```
x= 3
v = [0, 1, 4]

import numpy as np

for i in range (x):
    if i in v and B[i][0] == A[i][0]:
        A [i][1][0] = B[i][1][1]

for elem in v:
    if elem not in range (x):
        # get index (in this case: 2)
        ind = np.where(np.array([i[0] for i in B]) == elem)[0][0]
        A [elem][1][0] = B[ind][1][1][0]
        A [elem+1][1][0] = B[ind][1][1][1]
    else:
        A = A

print (A)
```